# Unsupported operand types (multiplication of array) codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to Multiply matrix with array in codeigniter. 
here's the details of array

```
$weight= Array ( [1] => 0.1740398414481 [2] => 0.10406921156399  )
$matrix_kr= Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [n] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [n] => 3 )) [2] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [n] => 9 ) [2] => Array ( [n] => 5 ))
```

and heres my controller

```
function count_k($jk){
  $matrix_kr= $this->get_mpk($jk);
  $weight = $this->get_eigen_vector($jk);
  $mat = array();
  for ($b=1; $b <= 1; $b++) { 
    for ($k=1; $k <= $jumlahKriteria; $k++) { 
      $mat[$b] += ($matrix_kr[$b][$k]*$weight[$k]);
      print_r($mat);
    }
  }
}
```

whats wrong with this? the problem bcause of different size of array or anything else? and how to fix it?

Comment: Please mention what issue are you facing in this code and in the for loop you have used $jumlahKriteria, where is it defined.

Comment: $jumlahKriteria is 9..i want to multiply the array, but its error "unsupport operand types", how to fix that error

Comment: Type cast the variable on multiplication. $mat[$b] += ((int) $matrix_kr[$b][$k] * (int) $weight[$k]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be $matrix_kr[$b][$k] should be $matrix_kr[$b][$k]['n']